# Do I need to keep all treasures?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

In Legend of Grimrock I've found some treasures, however they are occupying space in my inventory and adding weight to the carrying limit. Do I need to keep all of them with me for some reason or can I just leave them behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they give you an achievement, and without them you can't finish the game to 100%. Otherwise they're useless.

Comment: So you just need to *find* them, but not keep them in your inventory? Do you need to have all 7 at once to get the achievement (i.e keep them until you find them all) or can you get them separately/across multiple playthroughs?

Comment: With the achievements for matching sets of armor i'm pretty sure you need to be wearing them all at once on a single character.  I got the chitin armor one at the moment I equipped one of them pieces, **not** at the moment I picked it up.  So that means that if you are going for those achievements you need to save them, or stash them somewhere (near end of level is my recommendation) and mark the location on the map.  It's good to do this periodically anyway, ie put all your unneeded stuff in a big pile and mark it on the map.